# Number and masses of right-handed neutrinos in the seesaw mechanism

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mass, neutrinos, beyond-the-standard-model, majorana-fermions

In the [Wikipedia article about the seesaw mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seesaw_mechanism), it is argued that the seesaw mechanism "extends the Standard Model by assuming two or more additional right-handed neutrino fields", with the comment that "it is possible to generate two low-mass neutrinos with only one right-handed neutrino, but the resulting mass spectra are generally not viable".

Now my questions are: which experimental observations (neutrino mass differences and/or mixing angles?) disagree with having only one right-handed neutrino? Would it be viable to have *two* right-handed neutrinos with *equal* Majorana masses ($M_{R,1}=M_{R,2}$), while the Dirac masses are different ($m_{D,1}\neq m_{D,2}\neq m_{D,3}$ with $m_{D,3}=0$, implying one massless neutrino)? In this case, we would have an additional symmetry in the pure Majorana mass matrix. But this might not observable in the mixing matrix because the symmetry only affects the neutrino sector and not the charged-lepton sector. Is this correct?